# listbox keypress event in server side web form

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list box (GroupListBox) and I want to catch the enter key press event on this list box in a C# web form. I have tried many methods but no one is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in server side, You should use __doPostBack to get a postback.

Your listbox-

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" onkeydown="enterKeyPressed(event);">
            <asp:ListItem>one</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>two</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Three</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:ListBox>
```

Javascript function-

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function enterKeyPressed(e) {
         if (window.event) {
            e = window.event;
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            __doPostBack('ShowMessage', '');
        }
    }
</script>
```

In page's page load event-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, string.Empty);
        if (Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"] != null)
            if (Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"] == "ShowMessage")
            {
                Label1.Text = "Enter is pressed";
            }
 }
```

Comment: He mentioned "server-side" in his question, didn't he?